# MUI SvgIcon inherit viewBox from custom svg instead of default value

Tags: material-ui

```
import SvgIcon, { SvgIconProps } from '@mui/material/SvgIcon'

const NewSvgIcon = (props) => (
  <svg
    {...props}
    width="83"
    height="32"
    viewBox="0 0 83 32"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  >
    <path d="M59.9995 10.4115H67.5975V13.9172C68.7317 12.4794 69.8835 11.4632 71.044 10.8464C72.2088 10.2295 73.6233 9.91891 75.2918 9.91891C77.5471 9.91891 79.3119 10.6023 80.5907 11.9602C81.865 13.3181 82.5 15.4215 82.5 18.2616V31.9693H74.3065V20.1121C74.3065 18.7586 74.0612 17.8045 73.5708 17.2409C73.0715 16.6729 72.3796 16.3978 71.4819 16.3978C70.4965 16.3978 69.6908 16.7794 69.082 17.5338C68.469 18.2882 68.158 19.655 68.158 21.6164V31.9693H59.9995V10.4115V10.4115Z" />
    <path d="M46.9199 9.91815V13.4498H55.0917L46.9199 16.51V32H55.0917V9.91815H46.9199Z" />
    <path d="M24.1829 30.2067C21.967 31.2939 19.068 31.8353 15.4989 31.8353C10.8394 31.8353 7.17396 30.4508 4.507 27.6729C1.83129 24.8949 0.5 21.194 0.5 16.5744C0.5 11.6487 1.9977 7.65486 4.99748 4.59291C8.00163 1.53097 11.8948 0 16.6813 0C19.646 0 22.1509 0.381633 24.1829 1.14046V7.81905C22.1509 6.5854 19.8343 5.96857 17.2331 5.96857C14.3822 5.96857 12.0787 6.87828 10.327 8.69769C8.57969 10.5127 7.70385 12.9755 7.70385 16.0819C7.70385 19.055 8.52714 21.4292 10.1825 23.1953C11.8335 24.9615 14.0581 25.849 16.8565 25.849C19.5234 25.849 21.967 25.1878 24.1829 23.8698V30.2067ZM42.9742 15.4384C42.1641 14.9902 41.2225 14.7683 40.154 14.7683C38.7001 14.7683 37.5659 15.3141 36.7426 16.388C35.9237 17.4753 35.512 18.9397 35.512 20.799V31.2984H28.8249V9.31896H35.512V13.4015H35.5996C36.6637 10.4195 38.5643 8.92845 41.3189 8.92845C42.0283 8.92845 42.5757 9.0172 42.9742 9.18583V15.4384Z" />
  </svg>
)

const NewIcon = (props: SvgIconProps) => (
  <SvgIcon component={NewSvgIcon} {...props} inheritViewBox />
)

export default NewIcon
```

I want Mui SvgIcon to inherit viewBox from custom svg (viewBox="0 0 83 32"), but instead it is taking default viewBox = "0 0 24 24".

It seems I am missing something which I am not able to figure out, have tried all possble options which I could think of.

Thanks